# Filtering for group by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CqWG.png)

I have the following df and I want to check students taking both Physics and Chemistry.

I am trying to use groupby method and came up with the following coding.
I am open for any suggestions. Thank you

```
df1.groupby('Name').SubjectName.apply(list).agg(lambda x: (x[0] in ['Physics']) & (x[-1] in ['Chemistry']) )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You should post a text representation of your data or constructing code, instead of images.  Pictures make it harder for people to answer

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) to check if the set `{'Physics', 'Chemistry'}` is a subset of the aggregated lists:

```
subjects = {'Physics', 'Chemistry'}
df.groupby('Name').SubjectName.agg(list).apply(subjects.issubset)

# Name
# Albert    False
# Alice     False
# Jack       True
# Jill      False
# John       True
# Name: SubjectId, dtype: bool
```